# Wordpress - display-posts shortcode plugin has nextgen shortcode issue

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode, nextgen-gallery

I am using the plugin display-posts http://wordpress.org/support/plugin/display-posts-shortcode
which lets me display all posts (venues) from a particular category on a page, rather than just using a category. 
(This is so that I can in a higher up area of my website use the child-pages shortcode plugin to display a list of these pages (locations), as there seems to be no plugin available to display categories with a thumbnail chosen from one of its posts.)

The problem I am having is that I can set a featured image and text in the post to get pulled into this listing of posts page, but my nextgen gallery shortcode which I am using to display a selection of thumbnails for each venue within the post, is being displayed as plaintext and not activating the shortcode.

If I directly view the post on its own then the shortcode is working fine and the thumbs appear, I presume its something to do with using a shortcode within something already being generated by a shortcode?

This happens whether I am using include_excerpt="true" and manually placing the shortcode in the excerpt box as well as the main content area, or if I use include_content="true".

My shortcode in my page to pull in these posts is

[display-posts category="ayia-napa" order="ASC" orderby="title" include_excerpt="true" include_content="true"]

My shortcode for nextgen sat in individual post is

[ngg_images gallery_ids="1" display_type="photocrati-nextgen_basic_thumbnails"]

I'm not sure if the problem is specific to the plugin/code I am using or whether Wordpress has this problem in general.

I have followed advice online to include an add_filter in my functions.php file for showing shortcodes within excerpts but this doesn't seem to be working.

Thanks

Cathy